# I want to display 'n' number of rows depending on number chosen in spinner

Tags: javascript, php, loops, html-table, spinner

I have two PHP pages. One controls the form while the other displays a table. What my question is that I have spinner in the form which determines the number of questions, whatever number is displayed on that spinner, when the user submits it should display that same number of rows in the table.

for example if the Spinner = 25,then it should display 25 rows in the table and stating in the rows 1,2,3,4...up to 25 for the Question Id (`<td class="qid">`).

I know it would be using an if statement, loops and `$_POST` methods but I do not know how to code it. Does anyone know? I don't know if it should be done in php or javascript as javascript opens up the new window with the table and controls the spinner.

Below is code for the spinner and submit button (create_session.php)

```
<form action="create_session.php">
       <th>Number of Questions:</th>
                <td class="spinner"><textarea class="spinnerQuestion" id="txtQuestion" cols="2" rows="1"></textarea></td>
                <td><button class="scrollBtn" id="btnQuestionUp" type="button"><img src="Images/black_uppointing_triangle.png" alt="Increase" /></button>
                <button class="scrollBtn" id="btnQuestionDown" type="button"><img src="Images/black_downpointing_triangle.png" alt="Decrease" /></button></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div id="numberAlert"></div>
                <p><input class="questionBtn" type="button" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion" onClick="myClickHandler()"/></p>      <!-- Prepare Questions here-->

    </form>
```

Below is code for the table (QandATable.php)

```
   <table border=1 id="qandatbl" align:center;>
    <tr>
    <th class="col1">Question No</th>
    <th class="col2">Option Type</th>
    <th class="col1">Duration</th>
    <th class="col2">Weight(%)</th>
    <th class="col1">Answer</th>
    <th class="col2">Video</th>
    <th class="col1">Audio</th>
    <th class="col2">Image</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="qid"></td>
    <td class="options"></td>
    <td class="duration"></td>
    <td class="weight"></td>
    <td class="answer"></td>
    <td class="video"></td>
    <td class="audio"></td>
    <td class="image"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: To me it seems like you're in over your head. This is very basic stuff. You should take a break on your project to learn more about PHP, HTML, etc. then come back to it.

Comment: ur right, I am really an oracle and sql programmer but been forced to include php and javascript programming to get the functions working, no one else to do it but me :(

Comment: If you have any other programming experience I bet you could learn enough PHP to get by in just a few days - it's not a hard language.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like:

```
$spinnerCount = (int) $_POST['your_spinner_name'];
if($spinnerCount > 0) {
   for($i = 1; $i <= $spinnetCount; $i++) {
     //add your td here
   }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: keeps coming up with undefined notice for $_POST['txtQuestion']; when I submit which is strange